# In MEF how is the dependency chain of exports-imports evaluated?

Tags: mef

I'm facing an issue where I have App1.ClassA Importing App2.ClassB which itself needs to import App2.ClassC in a property. App1 and App2 are 2 different xaps

App1.ClassA invokes ComponentInitializer.SatisfyImports(this) in its initializing code. However this chain of satisfying imports does not seem to cascade down across assemblies.

I cannot specify ComponentInitializer on ClassB, since it is exporting itself (and MEF throws an error).However, ClassC is not being imported into the property of ClassB without this invocation.

Is this the expected behaviour or am i seeing some other bug due to which ClassC is not getting loaded ?

I went through this post -http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/202811.aspx, but the difference may be that i am crossing over Xaps in my scenario

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> i am crossing over Xaps in my scenario

By default, `ComponentInitializer` will find only parts in the **current XAP**. You can [override this default host configuration](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OverridingHostConfig&referringTitle=CompsitionInitializer) by calling `CompositionHost.Initialize`.

Answer (score 0):

The chain of resolving imports was being respected even when crossing over xap boundries. I'm guessing that xap boundries are not even an issue for xap, as it works at assembly level and as long as the assembly is available, it will resolve all the imports in the dependency chain.

The mistake i made was not realizing that the imports are not resolved during class instantiation( so the resolved elements are not available in the constructor). I had to hook up for the IPartInitialized Notification, and take action when this event is raised.

I'm marking this as the correct answer not to boost standings but to guide anyone facing the same issue.